# unable to update or insert a row in a table

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I want to update a row in my iPhone app. Below is the code. It shows in my log that query is executed and row has been updated, but when I excess that table, it seems to be empty. And also it always updates a row even if I am trying to enter a row with new id, it should insert instead of updating in this case.

```
 //create local database
NSString *docsDir = NULL;
 NSArray *dirPaths = NULL;
 sqlite3 *localDB = NULL;

 // Get the documents directory
 dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

 // Build the path to the database file
 NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"localscentsy1.db"]];
 NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);

 const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
 sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;

 if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &localDB) == SQLITE_OK)
 {

     NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Ratings set rating = '%d' WHERE perfume_id = ?",
                            (int)rating];


     const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
     if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(localDB, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL ) ==SQLITE_OK){

         sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, tappedItem.perfumeId);
     }

     char* errmsg;
     sqlite3_exec(localDB, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);

     if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement)){
         NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(localDB));

         NSLog(@"query failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(localDB));
         NSLog(@"%@",@"update unsuccessfull");
         NSLog(@"New data, Insert Please");

         sqlite3_stmt *statement2 = NULL;
         NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"INSERT INTO Ratings (perfume_id,rating) VALUES (\"%d\",\"%d\")",
                                tappedItem.perfumeId,
                                (int)rating];

         const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
         sqlite3_prepare_v2(localDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement2, NULL);
         if (sqlite3_step(statement2) == SQLITE_DONE)
         {
             NSLog(@"New data, Inserted");
         }
         sqlite3_finalize(statement2);

     }
     else{
         NSLog(@"%@",@"update successfull");
         sqlite3_finalize(statement);
     }


    sqlite3_close(localDB);
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated. I am new at ios development and this code is taking so much of my time. Here is my log which always says "update successful"

```
    CyberGenies/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/24D2FEE2-              DBE6-441A-AC79-1F2D57F96C88/Documents/localscentsy1.db
    2014-07-27 01:03:26.612 Scentsy Squirrel[19008:a0b] update successfull
```

Comment: You print out several error messages there.  What is printed?

Comment: no error messages, always "update successful"

Comment: Open a command window, navigate to the directory in the simulator, and start *sqlite3*.  Use it to examine the database "in situ" and try your query there.

Comment: As a best practice, make sure you are using `NSFileCoordinator` to control access to the database file(s). This will prevent a whole slew of difficult to troubleshoot problems.

Comment: @quellish - How do you use NSFileCoordinator with SQLite files?

Comment: @HotLicks same way you would with any other file.

Comment: ... but be sure to put the SQLite data in it's own directory, and use the presenter on the *directory*. The ensures all of SQLite's little files are protected.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I opened the database in sqlite browser and tried my queries. Database was created perfectly the only problem was that update query was not returning any error even if it fails. Knowning this I have slightly changed my code's logic and everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen if the db really has the structure? Some times when you start doing queries in an empty db (I mean not even tables) the query itself build the structure you are giving it on the query. You can check by compiling on the simulator and look for the db in the Mac finder.